# login y menu de seguridad por roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, seguridad, users-roles

Tengo un Proyecto con un web-form llamado login y una master.page llamada menu, tambien una serie de tablas donde tengo roles, usuarios y nombres de paginas, quisiera poder hacer cuando entre en el login y ponga las credenciales segun el rol que me aparezcan solo las opciones guardadas en una tabla, he investigado y varios ejemplos me salen con javascript y sus frameworks, pero yo no se ninguno de ellos hay alguna manera de hacerlo con c#, dejo las imagenes de las tablas y el menu.
[image: Tablas]

[image: Menu]

alguna idea o algun ejemplo que pudieran mostrarme, Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: Si pudiste resolverlo a tu manera man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que tienes una tabla de roles, usuarios y paginas (donde seguramente indicas si una recurso de pagina). Aqui una aclaracion mas que pagina puede ser por tareas mas enfocadas como por ejemplo crear un producto, eliminar un producto, etc. Pero bueno solo es una recomendación en base a lo que se deduce en tus tablas.

Te comento que en ASP.NET tienes [ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) que es la arquitectura y componentes para soportar este tema de Autenticacion y Autorizacion. Es la version mejorada por decirlo asi de lo que teniamos en versiones anteriores de ASP.NET membership.

Pero **¿Que opciones tienes con esta tipo de proyectos con tablas previamente creadas para la funcionalidad de autorizar recursos a los usuarios...?**

La opcion 1 es armar un **Proveedor de Rol personalizado en ASP.NET** (es una tarea ardua, que no se si es tu caso). En ASP.NET Identity es implementar un RolManager
Otra opcion 2 es armar nuevamente esta parte de roles pero utilizando lo que ASP.NET Identity ya viene "out-the-box", incluso te genera con EntityFramework toda la DB necesaria. (o puedes tener como la opcion 1 ASP.NET Identity sin EF sino personaliazando - escribiendo tu mismo - los proveedores de acceso)

- OPCION 1:
  [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity]
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Aqui vas a tener que mirar un poco como estan implementadas. Mas abajo dejo mas enlaces.

Existe una opcion 3 que es hacerlo manualmente, sin ASP.NET Identity. Pero tendrias que implementar tu propio mecanismo de Autorizacion/Atenticacion, es decir en cada accion del menu, en cada iteraccion en el servidor, preguntar en algun lugar o en la DB o cacheando los permisos del usuario.  Y a nivel de paginas para que no accedan tendrias que ver como Customizar/PErsonalizar el Proveedor de Rol (asi que es similar a la opcion 1)
Estaba buscando ejemplos de esto, lo unico que encontre es este post (asi que me anoto tambien para crear un ejemplo sin ASP.NET Identity)

- [No! You don't need to use ASP.NET Identity!](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/no-you-don-t-need-to-use-asp-net-identity)

RECOMENDACION 1:
Deberias evaluar en tu app cual es lo que quieres seguir, ver que involucra cada opcion. Y luego si seguimos con respuestas o en otras preguntas. Porque cada una es un mundo particular

RECOMENDACION 2: Tratar de implementar ASP.NET Identity con o sin EF

ME ha tocado realizado en clientes que tenian un DB Legacy (DB que vienen con muchos años ya implementadas con aplicciones un poco antiguas pero funcionando) que tienen el sistema de permisos o roles, asi que hay que ajustarse a ellos.

Como se utiliza Autorizacion en ASP.NET Webforms
Por ejemplo, puedes indicarlo por codigo o por carpeta (mediante web.config particulares o location en el web.config raiz de la app)

Por codigo
Esto mas facil de verlo pero mas "intrusivo"m ya que un condicional en el codigo y no es posible modificarlo sino compilarlo nuevamente

```
if(User.IsInRole("Rol1Ejemplo")){
   //accion...
 }
```

y por web.config (raiz, o carpeta, o location seccion web.config raiz)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        <authorization>
              <allow roles="Rol1Ejemplo"/>
               <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity)
- [Introducction to ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)
- [Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)
- [ASP.NET Core Identity Without Entity Framework](https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/)
  Si bien es para .NET Core, la el codigo de ejemplo utilizando Dapper te puede ayudar o utilizandolo o armando algo similar

Comment: Muchas Gracias lo investigare y lo hare gracias